# Map both Caps Lock and Escape to Escape

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I used dconf-editor to map caps to esc and esc to caps but I want esc to remain esc. How do I do that? Currently I put ['caps:escape'] under the xkb-options.

I believe that the command I run originally was `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "caps:swapescape"`. I read it somewhere and just blindly copy pasted it. The problem is it swapped my keys. All I wanted is to keep esc as it is and turn caps into esc.

BTW, I am on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please show more details about what you did. Also, if you mapped both to each other, couldn't you just remove the offending remapping?

Comment: I believe that the command I run originally was /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "caps:swapescape". I read it somewhere and just blindly copy pasted it. The problem is it swapped my keys. All I wanted is to keep esc as it is and turn caps into esc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`xmodmap`'s keycode number = name](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap) syntax to map a key to a symbol. The exact line you want seems to be

```
keycode 55 = Escape
```